# Disable caching in Apache 2 for Python Development

Tags: python, apache, caching, wsgi

Developing in Python using mod-python mod-wsgi on Apache 2.

All running fine, but if I do any change on my PY file, the changes are not propagated until I restart Apache `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.

This is annoying since I can't SSH and restart Apache service everytime in development.

**Is there any way to disable Apache caching?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Its a very bad setting from a performance point of view, but what I do in my http.conf is set `MaxRequestsPerChild` to 1.  This has the effect of each apache process handles a single request before dying.  It kills throughput (so don't run benchmarks with that setting, or use it on a production site), but it has the effect of giving python a clean environment for every request.

Comment: Because it is a very bad idea to do this, it is not something I would be suggesting unless you have no other choice. Even then, MaxRequestsPerChild only applies to mod_wsgi embedded mode and not mod_wsgi daemon mode. For proper explaination, read http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

Answer (score 2):

If you are using mod_wsgi you can use the [`WSGIScriptReloading`](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIScriptReloading) directive to enable you to issue a `touch your.wsgi` command and cause WSGI to reload the <strike>interpreter</strike> process.

Comment: The answer is a bit misleading. WSGIScriptReloading directive is on by default anyway, so never a need to set it. How it behaves though depends on what mode of mod_wsgi you are using. It only behaves like you say it does in daemon mode and even then it is not strictly reloading the interpreter, but killing off the process and restarting it. They aren't the same thing given that it is technically possible to destroy an intepreter and re initialise it in the same process. For proper explaination, read http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode